# How do I display my 'findall' results on it's own separate line?

Tags: python, regex, tkinter

Currently, all my results are being displayed as one long line, is there a way to separate the results so looks like this:

- "result 1"
- "result 2"
- "result 3"
- "result 4"

and so forth

here's the code I have:

```
Label(new_window, text = findall('<strong>(.*)</strong>', html_code)).pack()
```

Comment: `"\n".join(findall('<strong>(.*)</strong>', html_code))`? You should  also really be using a html parser like beautifulsoup or lxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex should actually be `(.*?)`? While we're on the subject of regular expressions....

***You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse html***. You should use an html parser.

But, to answer your question if you only want one `Label` widget

```
"\n".join(findall('<strong>(.*?)</strong>', html_code))
```

Otherwise, you could just use a forloop creating a new label for each widget, with the result in `findall` as the text and grid / pack each one on the grid according to the layout you want.